# change position and layout of table view and table view cell for iOS app in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have created a table view controller with a table view cell for my iOS app with storyboard in Xcode 6. In the cell I have an image and a label. At the top of the view controller I want to have a header and at the bottom I have a tab bar. That's my setup.

But now I want to change the position and the layout of the table view and the inherit cells, default they cover the whole screen. The table view should start below the header and should end above the tab bar. At the moment the cell content is displayed under the headline and the tab bar. Is it possible to set the positions of the table view and/or cell? And also I want to change the layout of the cells. I want to have some space between two cells and a corner radius.

THX!

Comment: Ha - so confusing, can you add a picture of the before and desired after looks?

Answer (score 1):

This is an old "problem". If you want to use a `UITableViewController`, the table view will cover the whole screen. In fact the `UIViewController`'s `view` property will be the table view.

If you want to have a table view **and other views** on the screen, you will have to use `UIViewController` and add two subviews to it's `view`: the header and the table view.

Do the following (which the `UITableViewController` would have done for you):

- add the table view as an ivar;
- have the class conform to `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` and
- set it to the table view's `delegate` and `datasource`